# Firebase: Is it possible to re-authenticate an anonymous user based on the `uid` that was generated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

**Problem**:

Visitors can place an order, pay for it and choose to create an account immediately, later with a link they receive in their mailbox or never.

While a visitor is creating an order, an account is being made with the `Firebase Auth anonymousSignIn` method.

All the data is placed in the realtime database under the generated uid. When they decide to create an account I'm linking the email/password provider to the current logged in user and done.

However, if they decide to wait and someone else logged in on the computer or created an account, the current logged in user has a different uid.

Therefore the question if it is possible to re-authenticate an anonymous user with the existing uid or link an Auth provider based on an uid.

If not, what could be a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If an anonymous user logs out, clears their cookies, or gets replaced by another anonymous login, that account is forever lost.  If you require that a user may log out and back in again, you will need for them to have a fully account through some authentication provider that can verify their identity given no other context.